# Oracle SQL procedure error I can't debug

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, plsql

I created the procedure below successfully, however when I run it, I get ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows error. 
Can anyone help in resolving my issue. Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_create_new_user AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
    vc_username VARCHAR2(50);
    vc_new_user VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT username
    INTO vc_username FROM marketing;

FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
    vc_new_user:=
     'CREATE USER '||vc_username||' IDENTIFIED BY password'||(i);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER '||vc_new_user||' HAS BEEN CREATED');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vc_new_user;
END LOOP;
END proc_create_new_user;
/

 EXECUTE proc_create_new_user;


error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select is giving you more than one record which you are trying to hold in a variable that can hold only one value. Try using a WHERE clause in your select statement.

```
SELECT username
INTO vc_username FROM marketing
WHERE userid = '1234';
```

Comment: Ok, but then would it still loop through each stored username?

Comment: If you're using SELECT INTO like you've used here, then there is going to be only one record at a time and there is no need for looping. If you want to do all the user name updation at once, you need to consider using cursors to fetch all records and then loop through them one by one and do the updation.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_create_new_user AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
 vc_username VARCHAR2(50);
 vc_new_user VARCHAR2(100);
 
 CURSOR cur_usernames IS
 SELECT username INTO vc_username 
 FROM marketing;
 
BEGIN
 FOR rec_cur_usernames IN cur_usernames LOOP
  vc_new_user:=
   'CREATE USER '||vc_username||' IDENTIFIED BY password';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER '||vc_new_user||' HAS BEEN CREATED');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vc_new_user;
 END LOOP;
END proc_create_new_user;
/

Comment: this says created, then when executed brings up error ORA-01935: missing user or role name

Comment: @ChantelleL - this is really a different question now, but in your create string you need to use `rec_cur_usernames.username` rather than `vc_username`, which is null - you don't need that variable at all, and the cursor shouldn't have the `into vc_username` part.